# Eulerian Paths in a Complete Graph $K_5$

Tags: combinatorics, graph-theory

As the title suggests, I’m simply looking for a method to compute the number of Eulerian Paths in the complete graph $K_5$, where all paths start from the same node. Since there are 5 nodes, all Eulerian paths must be Eulerian circuits as well.

Thanks.

Comment: what have you tried so far?

Comment: I’m not very knowledgeable about graph theory, but I wrote this problem and a friend of mine believes he has solved it with some super complex and obscure methods. I posted this because I wanted to see if there are any methods relatively easy [for me] to understand and also to confirm my friend’s answer. Thanks!

Comment: $K_5$ has $20$ times as many Eulerian trails (or "paths" in your quaint terminology) as Eulerian circuits. That's because a circuit has no starting point, so to make a circuit into a "path" you have to specify which edge is to be traversed first, and in which direction. Let me put it this way: if the graph were $C_5$ instead of $K_5$, is the answer you're looking for $1$ or $5$?

Comment: I'd attack the problem in two stages. First, enumerate the orientations of the graph (assigning a direction to each edge) such that each node has the same number of edges entering and leaving; then find the number of Eulerian circuits in each of the resulting digraphs. I don't know any "formula" for stage one. For $K_5$ because it's so small the first stage is easily done by hand: the number of such orientations is $\binom42\cdot2\cdot2=24$, and you can easily see that they are all isomorphic, so there is only one digraph to worry about in stage two.

Comment: There is a famous **determinant** formula for the number of Eulerian circuits in a digraph. I don't exactly remember it, I could look it up in my notes from the graph theory class I had years ago. Does that sound like the method your friend used?

Comment: Ah so sorry, thanks for bringing this to my attention. That lack of detail is my bad. I’ll edit the original question, but for my question I’m asking for the number of paths (or trails) all from the same starting point. So, as per your example, if the graph were C₅ then the answer I’d be looking for would actually be 2. The actual problem I wrote is a word problem with bridges, but I hope you get the idea. If I’ve poorly phrased my question in any other way please let me know. Thanks!

Comment: If you just want to check your friend's answer you could just work out the correct answer from [this site](http://oeis.org/search?q=eulerian+circuits+complete+graph&language=english&go=Search). They give $264$ Eulerian circuits for $K_5$. But each Eulerian  circuit goes through your designated starting point twice, so I guess that means you get $528$ for your problem. Is that what your friend got?

Comment: Hahaha, I didn’t even think to check OEIS... my friend in fact got $264$ as his answer, so I guess I can tell him he’s wrong :) I don’t  believe he used the determinant formula you mentioned. He told me something about using a modified gamma function.... I was just searching for an easier way to understand the solution.

Comment: Or actually, never mind that, I think he is right. OEIS says 264 is the number of directed Eulerian circuits, so that accounts for the two directions.

Answer (score 1):

Without using fancy tools like the [BEST theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/BEST_theorem), we can figure out the problem using inclusion-exclusion.

At each vertex of $K_5$, we have $4$ edges. A circuit is going to enter the vertex, leave, enter, and leave again, dividing up the edges into two pairs. There are $\frac12 \binom42 = 3$ ways to pair up the edges, so there are $3^5 = 243$ ways to make this decision at every vertex.

Not all of these will correspond to an Eulerian circuit, because not all of them connect up the way we'd like. We could also see:

- Two $5$-cycles (first diagram below). There are $\frac{5!}{2 \cdot 5} = 12$ ways to choose a $5$-cycle, and they'll always go together, so we should subtract $6$.
- A $4$-cycle and some other stuff (second diagram below). There are $\binom{5}{4} \cdot 3 = 15$ ways to choose a $4$-cycle, and $3$ ways to decide what happens at the vertex it doesn't visit, so we should subtract $15\cdot3 = 45$.
- A $3$-cycle and some other stuff (third diagram below). There are $\binom 53 = 10$ ways to choose a $3$-cycle, and $3^2$ ways to decide what happens at the two vertices it doesn't visit, so we should subtract $10 \cdot 3^2 = 90$.

[image]

But $243 - 6 - 45 - 90 = 102$ is still wrong, because we've double-counted one case. It's possible to have $3$ components: a $4$-cycle and two $3$-cycles (last diagram above). If we've chosen the $4$-cycle, there is one way to pair up the edges at the unvisited vertex to get the two $3$-cycles as well, so there's $15$ such configurations. We've subtracted them *three* times instead of once, so we should add them back in twice, getting $102 + 30 = 132$.

Multiplying by the two possible orientations, we get $264$ oriented Eulerian circuits. If we know which *node* is the first, but not which *edge* is the first, we can also start with two possible edges out of that node, getting $528$ oriented Eulerian paths starting at that node ($2640$ oriented Eulerian paths total).

Comment: BEST is useless anyway, since we are talking about undirected graphs.

Comment: It was suggested in the comments on the question that we can try applying it to each possible orientation of $K_5$. Not sure how practical that is.

Comment: @MishaLavrov I think it is practical for $K_5$ because all Eulerian orientations of $K_5$ are isomorphic.

Comment: @bof Oh, good point. I was just thinking of in general, where it has to be hard in order for the problem to be #P-complete.

Comment: I recall many years ago calculating the number of Eulerian circuits in $K_7$ (poresented as a puzzle about arranging a set of dominos) using three instances of the BEST theorem.

Comment: @MishaLavrov Thank you! Exactly the type of explanation/solution I was looking for. Very smart way of going about it.